# Is breath holding effective to prevent sleep paralysis?

Tags: treatment-options, breathing, effectiveness

I constantly get sleep paralysis (the feeling of being awake in my mind but asleep in my body). I do not like the sensation, and am trying to battle it as much as possible.

One of my friends has told me to try to hold my breath when I am asleep. I was wondering whether if this has been shown to be an effective way to treat sleep paralysis? What are the common reasons that people get sleep paralysis and what treatments are available?